# How to package an application with system libraries into AppImage

Tags: ubuntu, path, linker, appimage

So I have a binary that links to system library files (.so) (for ex, ones under /usr, and ones under /opt)

when generating an AppImage, I was copying the whole /usr into the AppDir and updating `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but I doubt that this is the right way of doing it.

is there a tutorial about how to do this right?
Can anyone give some directional guide?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of making an AppImage. The one you're using is one of them. There are tools that ease the packaging process for you. I would recommend you using appimage-builder.

You can find the documentation at: https://appimage-builder.readthedocs.io/
For more information in general about AppImages go to: https://docs.appimage.org/